# Parsing SHOUTcast 7.html metadata on Android

Tags: android, html, parsing, shoutcast

I am trying to check the status of a SHOUTcast stream using this URL:

```
http://85.17.167.136:8684/7.html
```

... which returns data like:

```
<HTML><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"></head><body>7,1,77,100,7,128,+44(0)7908 340 811 Follow Us @visionradiouk</body></html>
```

I know that the after the first comma returns 1 if the stream is up and running or returns 0 if the stream is down. My problem is getting the html of that page? I use this code, which works on other websites like Google etc.

```
    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


String htmlCode = "";

try {
    URL url = new URL("http://85.17.167.136:8684/7.html"); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null)
        htmlCode += inputLine;
    System.out.println(htmlCode);
    tView.setText(htmlCode);
    in.close();     
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");
}


}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, I have tried other solutions from this and other forums but they seem to have errors, maybe it is old code that is deprecated.

Comment: DI done what I needed by following this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388560/read-shoutcasts-7-html-with-java which shows this code.           URL url = new URL("http://molestia.ponify.me:8062/7.html");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); // This bugger right here saved the day!

Reader r = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

while (true) {
    int ch = r.read();

    if (ch < 0)
        break;

    buf.append((char) ch);
}

String str = buf.toString();

Log.d("HTML", str);

Comment: Sorry my last comment is not formatted properly, I am using a phone and pressing return does not give me a new line to add spaces for code.

Comment: excellent, thanks a lot dude, i was tearing my hair out trying to get similar code to work, you are right, all the available code doesn't work, your code works perfectly, cheers! :D

BTW you should probably add it as a proper answer, with proper formatting, so others can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres Pulsarman325's working solution, tidied up, with a little extra stuff i had to add to get it to work (try/catch and variable initialisations)

```
String url = "http://molestia.ponify.me:8062";

URL url2=null;

try
{
    url2 = new URL(url + "/7.html");

}

catch (MalformedURLException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

URLConnection con=null;

try
{
    con = url2.openConnection();
}

catch (IOException e1)
{
  e1.printStackTrace();

}

con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

Reader r = null;

try
{
    r = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
}

catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace(); 
}

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

int ch=0;

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        ch = r.read(); 
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    if (ch < 0)
      break;

    buf.append((char) ch);

}

String str = buf.toString();

String trackinfo = str.split(",")[6].split("</body>")[0];

Log.d("HTML", trackinfo);
```