# Accessing Shoutcast Current Stream Information

Tags: java, android, http, audio-streaming, shoutcast

i am creating an internet radio application for android. So far i have successfully streamed and played using the shoutcast url for various stations.This is my code :

```
      String url = "http://185.33.22.13:7704"; 
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Next i would want to get the information of stream to be shown in my application.
I want to retrieve the information shown in green box:

[image]

People have posted about FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever but github is way out of my league to understand also tried thier apk file which does nothing when given the above http link.Please suggest me a simple and robust solution to retrieve the data from SHOUTcast DNAS status.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Append "/;" this with you redirect url and see how it works means your url will look something like this "http://185.33.22.13:7704/;"

Comment: @sunilsunny That is not the real issue and it is working well without the "/"

Answer (score 2):

Shoutcast V1 has a special page with bitrate and other information.

If your shoutcast is running on 
http://185.33.22.13:7704

then this page url will be:
http://185.33.22.13:7704/7.html

The body of that page looks like this:

```
 <HTML><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"></head><body>214,1,312,1000,213,64,Ferry Tayle - The Way Back Home (Edit) (feat. Poppy)</body></html>
```

Split that text by commas and you will get:

- Current listeners
- Stream status
- Peak listeners
- Maximum number of listeners (from server start)
- Unique listeners
- Bitrate
- Song title

Here is an example in javascript (Nodejs) that gets the data from 7.html page and parses it:

```
var request = require('request'),
    options = {
        url: 'http://185.33.22.21:7704/7.html',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
        }
    },
    regex = /<body>(.*?)<\/body>/i;

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    var match = regex.exec(body),
        data = match[1].split(',');

    console.log("7.html: ", body);

    console.log("Current listeners: ", data[0]);
    console.log("Stream status: ", data[1]);
    console.log("Peak listeners: ", data[2]);
    console.log("Maximum number of listeners: ", data[3]);
    console.log("Unique listeners: ", data[4]);
    console.log("Bitrate: ", data[5]);
    console.log("Metada: ", data[6]);
});
```

Please note that setting "User-Agent" header is required.

If you have admin password from that server - then another way is to get XML data directly from shoutcast admin page using the following URL:

> http://185.33.22.13:7704/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml

Comment: Tried to get the data from 7html using the solution given in this thread.But it does not show me any results.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767015/parsing-shoutcast-7-html-metadata-on-android

Comment: Bdw how do i get the admin credentials for Shoutcast where do i need to register?

Comment: I'm not a Java guy, but I think splitting a string by commas is easy enough in any language. First of all you need to remove all HTML from the page and get the BODY tag contents.

Comment: Admin credentials can be provided by the station administrators/owners.

Comment: Try using something like "<body>(.*?)</body>" regular expression to get body contents